# Can I develop Win CE 6.0 / R3 application on XP run under Virtual PC?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, virtual-machine

I have Windows 7 x64 PC. I need to develop small Win CE 6.0 app (probably with R3 installed) using C# and CF.NET

**I am going to install Virtual PC under W7 and then install XP on it and then VS2008 and Win CE... Will it work?**

Device is some motorolla with CE 6.0 support.

**Will it be possible to connect actual device** or I will have to stick to the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do the development under Virtual PC.  You *can not* use the emulator under Virtual PC (it would require running a virtual machine inside a virtual machine, which isn't a working scenario).  I don't think you can use the USB connection for debugging either - I think VMWare does allow this.  I say "don't think" because I can't remember the last time I tried debugging over USB at all - it's been years.  You *can*, however, [debug over ethernet without ActiveSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) just fine and it's faster than USB.

BTW, for appliction development you're not going to need to install Platform Builder at all, so you might want to save the time and headache and not bother.

Comment: Sorry. I did an odd job for Win Mobile 6 yrs ago.. I thoroughly forgot all the basics even... Could you please clarify, are you saying I can use actual device through ethernet to debug application running under Microsoft VM ? But I cant do that with emulator. Is that right? ... if yes than thats Ok... as long as I can debug in any way feasible...

Comment: Yes, you must use a physical device. It has to be ethernet capable (WiFi counts) and on the same network as the virtual machine. I've added a link in my answer.